# What do the "runes" on this pendant say?

Tags: norse, interpretation, runes

I found this pendant on AliExpress, and it looks pretty nice. But I'd like to know what the runes mean, if anything?

[image]

Comment: This may qualify as a holy symbol for one of the [reconstructed "Heathen" religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathenry_(new_religious_movement)), and wearing it may give people the impression that you adhere to one of those yourself.

Answer (score 20):

Sorry to say, it's actually nothing more than the [Elder Futhark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Futhark), the eldest of the runic alphabets.

[image]

You can read more on it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Futhark). A good giveaway that it doesn't "say" anything is the lack of repeating characters on the pendant.

Comment: Something to do with [alpha to omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_and_Omega) ?

Answer (score 11):

As others said, the symbols spell the runic alphabet from the Elder Futhark. They circle Yggdrasil, the mythical tree that connects the nine worlds in Norse cosmology, where Odin hung himself in order to attain the knowledge that he shares with those who pursue runemal.

Comment: I didn't even think to comment on Yggdrasil. You're absolutely right. To better serve the community, in case some aren't familiar with the myth, do you think you can add some sources to your answer? Thanks and welcome to Mythology.StackExchange!

Answer (score 8):

This is literally the Elder Futhark runic alphabet spelled out. In other words it's the equivalent of "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"